# WPF Image is blurred

Tags: wpf, image, resolution, dpi

I have some png images that are used in a WPF application.  They are the exact size I want them, but they are being 'muddied' when brought into the application.  I've done some research here and it looks like it's a DPI issue as they were given to me at 72 DPI and WPF is trying to scale them to 96 (at least that seems to be the likely culprit).

I tried to resize them in Photoshop to 96 dpi but for some reason it stubbornly sticks to 96.012dpi whenever I save it, it won't stay exactly at 96.  It helps, but the display is still not crisp like the original image and I suspect that it's because WPF is trying to scale the image to 96 dpi and blurring it a little in the process.

Has anyone encountered this?  Is there a way to force the image to 96 or stop it from scaling somehow?  I tried setting the size directly and Stretch="None" with the same result.

Here is the original image zoomed in (background color was added to match the other for comparison, the dark color is the image and it has transparency):

[image]

and here is a screen capture from within the program zoomed in:

[image]

I also can set bitmap scaling to nearest neighbor and it helps a little, but it shouldn't be scaling the image at all...

Comment: Does playing with the `RenderingOptions` attached properties help? [RenderingOptions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.renderoptions(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: No, it modifies it just a bit but it doesn't change the scaling at all.

Comment: Did you try setting SnapsToDevicePixels="true" on the window?

Comment: I did that on the image, should I do it on the window as a whole?